# Problema en laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy teniendo problemas con el Blade, por ejemplo, estoy con este código

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Portfolio')



@section('content')
<h1>Portfolio</h1>

<ul>

    @isset($portfolio)
    
        @foreach ($portfolio as $portfolioItem)

            <li>{{ $portfolioItem['title'] }} </li>

        @endforeach 

        @else 

            <li>No hay proyecto para mostrar</li>

     @endisset
    
</ul>
```

Cuando le quito los @endcontent funciona la página, pero cuando les pongo no, además la navegación me sale por debajo de bucle, alguna forma de arreglarlo (estoy comenzando en laravel)

Comment: Prueba a poner `@if($portfolio)` y `@endif` en vez de @isset y @endisset

Comment: Sigue igual, ha cambiado nada

Comment: Te falta poner @endsection al final

Comment: cuando pongo @endsection no funciona

Comment: Y si le pones @stop?

Comment: **Cuando le quito los @endcontent funciona la página, pero cuando les pongo n** ¿qué no funciona, aparece algún error?, procura ser mas claro y proveer los detalles del error mínimos para saber como ayudar

Comment: ¿has mirado su tu plantilla "layout" de la cual haces extends tiene las secciones `title` y `content` que estás rellenando?
Sin ver más parece que tu layout no tiene los *huecos* donde le mandas contenido.